# Items reposition/jumps in StaggaredGrid while scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, paging

I'm using paging(RemoteMediator) and I collect the flow in my main thread like this

```
 val pictures: LazyPagingItems<PicturesItem> = viewModel.pictures.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
```

but the items of the list keeps repositioning and the list itself disappears for half a second and return to the screen again as well as the list being laggy when scrolling up or down.

At the start of the app when it enters the screen that holds the Grid the paging loads 4 pages at the start without any scrolling at all.

You can see the problem clearer in this [video](https://imgur.com/a/IG691Sa)

What first came in my mind was to use Item keys like this

```
items(pictures.itemCount,
                key = pictures.itemKey { it.id },
                contentType = pictures.itemContentType{ it }) { index ->
                pictures[index]?.let{
                    PictureItem(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        item = it,
                        onItemClicked = onPictureItemClicked,
                        height = (it.height / 12)
                    )
                }
            }
```

But this however didn't work and didn't even changes anything even though the item.id is a unique variable for each item, still the same problem.

Second thing I tried was to replace the images with just a text to see if the library that loads the images is the problem but unfortunately it was the same exact problem even with just texts as the items with no pictures

I will share my code for the RemoateMediator and the Home Screen and the ViewModel

ViewModel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class PictureViewModel  @Inject constructor(
    private val getPictures: GetPictures,
    private val getFeatured: GetFeatured,
    private val fetchFeatured: FetchFeatured,
    private val mainDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : ViewModel(){

    private val _pictures : MutableStateFlow<PagingData<PicturesItem>> = MutableStateFlow(value = PagingData.empty())
    val pictures: StateFlow<PagingData<PicturesItem>> =
        _pictures.asStateFlow()


    private val _featured = MutableStateFlow<List<PicturesItem>?>(null)
    val featured: StateFlow<List<PicturesItem>?> =
        _featured.asStateFlow()


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(mainDispatcher) {
            fetchFeatured()
            subscribeToFeaturedUpdates()
            subscribeToPicturesUpdates()
        }
    }



    private fun subscribeToPicturesUpdates() {
        viewModelScope.launch(mainDispatcher) {

            getPictures().distinctUntilChanged().cachedIn(viewModelScope).collect {
                onNewPicturesList(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun subscribeToFeaturedUpdates() {
        viewModelScope.launch(mainDispatcher) {

            getFeatured().collect{
                onNewFeaturedList(it)
            }
        }
    }


    private suspend fun onNewPicturesList(pictures: PagingData<PicturesItem>) {
        Logger.d("Got more Pictures $pictures")
        _pictures.emit(pictures)
    }

    private suspend fun onNewFeaturedList(pictures: List<PicturesItem>) {
        Logger.d("Got more Featured $pictures")
        _featured.emit(pictures)
    }

}
```

Home Screen:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    onPictureItemClicked: OnPictureItemClicked,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: PictureViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {


    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(10.dp),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        val listState = rememberLazyStaggeredGridState()
        val featured by viewModel.featured.collectAsState()
        val pictures: LazyPagingItems<PicturesItem> = viewModel.pictures.collectAsLazyPagingItems()

        LazyVerticalStaggeredGrid(
            state = listState,
            columns = if (LocalConfiguration.current.orientation == ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                StaggeredGridCells.Adaptive(minSize = 175.dp)
            } else StaggeredGridCells.Fixed(2)
        ) {

            item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine, content = {
                featured?.let { Featured(it) }
            })

            item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(15.dp))
            }

            item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
                Text(
                    text = "All",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(5.dp),
                    color = Color.White.copy(alpha = 0.9f)
                )
            }

            item(span = StaggeredGridItemSpan.FullLine) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(5.dp))
            }


            items(pictures.itemCount,
                key = pictures.itemKey { it.id },
                contentType = pictures.itemContentType{ it }) { index ->
                pictures[index]?.let{
                    PictureItem(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize(),
                        item = it,
                        onItemClicked = onPictureItemClicked,
                        height = (it.height / 12)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

}


@Composable
private fun PictureItem(
    item: PicturesItem,
    onItemClicked: OnPictureItemClicked,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    height : Int
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(5.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .clickable { onItemClicked(item) }
            .height(height.dp),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
        ),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 8.dp
        )
    ) {

        val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(item.urls.small)
        val transition by animateFloatAsState(
            targetValue = if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) 1f else 0f,
            label = ""
        )

        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .alpha(transition),
            contentDescription = "custom transition based on painter state")

    }
}
```

RemoteMediator:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
class PicturesRemoteMediator(
    private val cache: Cache,
    private val picturesApi: PicturesApi) : RemoteMediator<Int, CachedPicture>() {

    override suspend fun initialize(): InitializeAction {
        return InitializeAction.SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH
    }

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, CachedPicture>
    ): MediatorResult {
        return try {

            val loadKey = when (loadType) {
                LoadType.REFRESH -> 1
                LoadType.PREPEND ->
                    return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = true)
                LoadType.APPEND -> {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        val count = cache.getItemsCount()
                        return@withContext (count / PAGE_SIZE) + 1
                    }
                }
            }

            

            val response = picturesApi.getPictures(loadKey.toLong())
            if (loadType == LoadType.REFRESH) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    cache.deletePictures()
                }
            }

            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                response.forEach {
                    cache.storePictures(CachedPicture.fromDomain(it))
                }
            }

            MediatorResult.Success(
                endOfPaginationReached = response.isEmpty()
            )

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```